# How can I convert this React Native code from version 0.59.10 to version 0.72.5?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am receiving an error on the initialRouteName: `'Notifications' property,` and I have tried several solutions but have been unsuccessful. I am new to React Native, and I would appreciate any help that I can get.

```
const NotificationStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
      Notifications:{                           //PAGE: To-Do => List Of Leave
          screen: Notification,
          navigationOptions:{
              title: 'Notifications'
          }
      },
      //#region Leave Application
      AllApprovalInToDo: {                      //PAGE: To-Do => All List Of Leave
          screen: AllApprovalInToDo,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Approval Leave Request',
            headerBackTitle: 'Back',
            headerStyle:{
                backgroundColor: Blue,
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            }
        }
      },
      ApprovalItem: {                         //PAGE: To-Do => Leave Detail
        screen: ApprovalItem,
      },
      LeaveApprovalToDoFilter: {              //PAGE: To-Do => Leave Filter
        screen: PendingLeaveApprovalFilter
      },
      //#endregion Leave Application
      //#region Overtime
      OvertimeApprovalDetail: {               //PAGE: To-Do => Overtime Detail
        screen: OvertimeApprovalDetail
      },
      OvertimeAllApproval: {                  //PAGE: To-Do => All List of Overtime
        screen: OvertimeAllApproval
      },
      OvertimeApprovalFilter: {               //PAGE: To-Do => Overtime Filter Page
        screen: OvertimeApprovalFilter
      }
      //#endregion Overtime
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Notifications',
  },
);
```

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fa6y.png)

> When I tried to convert my React Native code from version 0.59.10 to 0.72.5, I received the error initialRouteName: 'Notifications'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create a navigator.  you have to update your react-navigation to latest versions as well.

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React from 'react';
import fonts from '../constants/fonts';
import { moderateScale } from '../constants/scaling';
import theme from '../constants/theme';
import DialPadScreen from '../screens/DialPadScreen';
import GettingStartedScreen from '../screens/GettingStartedScreen';
import PrivacyPolicyScreen from '../screens/PrivacyPolicyScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import SearchScreenResults from '../screens/SearchScreenResults';
import UserProfileRegisterationScreen from '../screens/UserProfileRegisterationScreen';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function AuthStack() {
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={"GettingStartedScreen"}
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: theme.primaryColor,
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
          fontSize: moderateScale(16),
          color: theme.primaryColor,
        },
        headerBackTitleStyle: {
          color: theme.primaryColor,
        },
        animation:"slide_from_right",
        animationDuration:5000,
        headerShown: true,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="GettingStartedScreen"
        options={{headerShown: false}}
        component={GettingStartedScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PrivacyPolicyScreen"
        options={{title: 'Privacy Policy'}}
        component={PrivacyPolicyScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="UserProfileRegisterationScreen"
        component={UserProfileRegisterationScreen}
        options={{title: 'User Register Profile'}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SearchScreen"
        component={SearchScreen}
        options={{title: 'Phone Caller ID'}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DialPadScreen"
        component={DialPadScreen}
        options={{title: 'Dial Paid'}}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="SearchScreenResults"
        component={SearchScreenResults}
        options={{title: 'Search Results'}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AuthStack;
```